# Add specific selected fields in plotly text annotations

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a graph that looks like this:
[image]

I want to color the dots in the following way, one dot for every time the version is different, like for `0.1-SNAPSHOT` there are 8 dots, but I only want the first one labelled and the rest just dots (without the version),similarly for all others.

This is how my data looks like:

```
        API_paths      info_version      Commit-growth  
24425   0             0.1-SNAPSHOT           52 
24424   20            0.1-SNAPSHOT           104    
24423   35            0.1-SNAPSHOT           156    
24422   50            0.1-SNAPSHOT           208    
24421   105           0.1-SNAPSHOT           260    
24420   119           0.1-SNAPSHOT           312    
24419   133           0.1-SNAPSHOT           364    
24576   0             0.1-SNAPSHOT           408    
24575   1             0.9.26 (BETA)          504    
24574   13            0.9.27 (BETA)          600    
24573   15            0.9.28 (BETA)          644    
24416   161           0.9.28                  28
24415   175           0.9.29                  29
24572   29            0.9.29 (BETA)          792    
24571   42            0.9.30 (BETA)          836
```

Right now they are colored quite simple:
`fig = px.scatter(data1, x='Commit-growth', y='API_paths', color='info_version')`

and annotated this way:

```
data1= final_api.query("info_title=='Cloudera Datalake Service'").sort_values(by='commitDate')
# data1['Year-Month'] = pd.to_datetime(final_api['Year-Month']) 
data1['Commit-growth']= data1['commits'].cumsum()

import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure()

fig = px.scatter(data1, x='commitDate', y='API_paths', color='info_version')
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(mode='lines',
                         x=data1["commitDate"],
                         y=data1["API_paths"],
                         line_color='black',
                         line_width=0.6,
                         line_shape='vh',
                         showlegend=False
                       )
             )

for _,row in data1.iterrows():
    fig.add_annotation(
        go.layout.Annotation(
            x=row["commitDate"],
            y=row["API_paths"],
            text=row['info_version'],
            showarrow=False,
            align='center',
            yanchor='bottom',
            yshift=9,
            textangle=-90)
       )

fig.update_layout(template='plotly_white', title='Cloudera Datalake Service API Paths Growth',title_x=0.5,
                  xaxis_title='Number of Commit', yaxis_title='Number of Paths')
fig.update_traces(marker_size=10, marker_line_width=2, marker_line_color='black', showlegend=False, textposition='bottom center')

fig.show()
```

I am not sure how to achieve this, so I am a bit lost, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please include a fully reproducible code snippet, or your question may be closed.

Comment: I edited the question to add the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a duplicate row of first occurrence to drive the text of your annotations.

```
df['dupe'] = df.info_version.where(~df.info_version.duplicated(), '')

|    |   API_paths | info_version   |   Commit-growth | dupe      |
|---:|------------:|:---------------|----------------:|:----------|
|  0 |           0 | 0.1-snap       |              52 | 0.1-snap  |
|  1 |          20 | 0.1-snap       |             104 |           |
|  2 |          35 | 0.1-snap       |             156 |           |
|  3 |          50 | 0.1-snap       |             208 |           |
|  4 |         105 | 0.1-snap       |             260 |           |
|  5 |         119 | 0.1-snap       |             312 |           |
|  6 |         133 | 0.1-snap       |             364 |           |
|  7 |           0 | 0.1-snap       |             408 |           |
|  8 |           1 | 0.9-other      |             504 | 0.9-other |
|  9 |          13 | 0.9-other      |             600 |           |
| 10 |          15 | 0.9-other      |             644 |           |
| 11 |         161 | 0.9-other      |              28 |           |
| 12 |         175 | 0.9-other      |              29 |           |
| 13 |          29 | 0.9-other      |             700 |           |
| 14 |          42 | 0.9-other      |             500 |           |
```